# What makes some things easier to parse than others?

Tags: data-structures, parsing, syntax

I was just reading the Wikipedia page for [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) and it says: “*WebAssembly is… designed to be faster to parse than JavaScript*” , which got me thinking, what makes a certain language or data format faster to parse than others and what parsing algorithms are used?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This topic is very complex. You can google for parser algorithms and you'll get plenty of detailed material.

In general:

- The fewer ambiguities must be resolved, the faster the parsing
  process.
- The more tokens have to be considered before a decision
  can be made, the more complex it gets.

For example:
When a JS parser sees the `function` keyword in this code: `function xyz(a, b) {}`, the function keyword is ambigous. It first has to process the next token `xyz` and see that it is an identifier before it can decide that it is a function declaration.

However, if the next token were a `(` we are dealing with a function literal: `function(a, b) {}`. That requires the parser to behave very differently, thus more code in the parser, thus slower execution.

If there were different keywords for these two purposes, there would be no ambiguity:

`function_decl xyz(a, b, c) {}` and `function_lit(a, b, c) {}`

However, nobody would want to write in such a language. But WebAssembly is not supposed to be written by hand. That allows the language to be tailored towards machines, rather than humans.

Comment: Would this mean that Lisp is very easily parsed?

Comment: @Moses: Yes, writing a naive lisp parser is trivial, because the syntax is homoiconic with the structure of an abstract syntax tree and almost no ambiguities exist.

Comment: Another good example is bytecode, often can be parsed with a looping switch statement and that's it.

Comment: @whatsisname Indeed, the same applies to regular Assembly and Web Assembly